# Flutter: "Cannot resolve symbol '@android:color/white'" while changing splash screen

Tags: android, xml, splash-screen

I was following [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-2019-real-splash-screens-tutorial-16078660c7a1) tutorial to add a Splash Screen to an app.

I added the image to the `drawable` folder and I modified line 10 accordingly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

<!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image.png" />
</item>
```

The preview keeps loading and both @android and @drawable colored in red.
When I hover I get the same message: 'Cannot resolve symbol @...'.
How to solve the error?

Comment: This should be marked as an Android question, not Flutter.

Answer (score 1):

As the item says drawable it shouldn't be a color. Try marking it as:

```
<item android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

`@android:color/white` can only be used in a color, background or textColor. For drawable you should assign drawable XML or images inside your drawable or mipmap resource

Answer (score 0):

android:src="@drawable/my_image.png
Remove the @ sign Infront of the drawable and remove the extension of the image . It's should be this way instead

android:src="drawable/my_image